# How to supply Chapters to JSON Feed?

Tags: json, jwplayer, feed, playlist

I have a JW Player (7.x) that I am using to display a JSON json feed ([link](https://www.scottgoodrow.com/files/podcasts/srvusd/playlist.json)), but I can't figure out how to setup the formatting so that the referenced .vtt file is properly processed for chapters.

Do JSON feeds not support chapters? Documentation suggests that they do, so I suspect I am not formatting something correctly. Help!

JSON Feed (does not work):

```
playerInstance.setup({
  skin: { name: "seven" },
  playlist: "https://www.scottgoodrow.com/files/podcasts/srvusd/playlist.json",
  width: "100%",
  aspectratio: "16:9"
});
```

Direct Playlist (works):

```
playerInstance.setup({ 
  skin: { name: "seven" },
  playlist: [{
    file: "https://archive.org/download/SRVUSD/170502_srvusd_boe_cropped.mp3",
    image: "https://archive.org/download/SRVUSD/170502_srvusd_boe_cropped.jpeg",
    title: "170502 SRVUSD BOE Cropped",
    mediaid: "170502_srvusd_boe_cropped",
    tracks: [{
      file: "https://www.scottgoodrow.com/files/podcasts/srvusd/170502_srvusd_boe_cropped.vtt",
      kind: "chapters"
    }]
  }],
  width: "100%",
  aspectratio: "16:9"
});
```

Comment: Shoot. Turned out that my JSON file had "track" instead of "tracks", so this is fully resolved. Going to leave it here as an example though I guess?